# Creating Postgres Varchar Array Columns with Liquibase

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, liquibase

Since using Arrays in columns is still more of a NoSQL than RDBMS way of storing a list, I understand that Liquibase doesn't officially support the type. However, when I use the PSQL statements from the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/arrays.html), I get the following:

```
<column name="widgets" type="varchar(8)[]" />
```

Trace output:

```
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "("
...
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "("
```

The vary same DDL works as expected when run from the PSQL command line.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It must be a bug of sorts in the PSQL parser. Just adding a space fixes it.

```
<column name="widgets" type="varchar(8) []" />
```

Liquibase must be changing the SQL string in some mior way.

Comment: I was facing the same issue for <column name="day_exclusions" type="int []">. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I just tried this out and the problem is still present.

Comment: Can you please share the syntax for liquibase changeset?, to insert the int/string array like ```<column name="myintarray" value="('1','3','2')">``` or ```<column name="mystringarray" value="('aa','bb','cc')">```